# TextBoxFor int? in ASP.NET mvc 4. Exception if user enters value what exceeds max int size

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, validation

I have a web form (c# asp.net mvc 4) where user can enter some digits. 
Here is a part of code from a model:

```
[Range(1, Int32.MaxValue)] 
public int? MyVariable { get; set; }
```

But this one does not help when user enter value what is more that maxint, for example '999999999999'. In this case I have an exception on server that value exceeds max int. 
Is there a way to validate this situation? 
I see two ways but do not like both:

- After click on submit button use javascript to check is value more than 2,147,483,647. If more I do not submit for and show error message. Also I need to create div on page for it what is not a good idea when you have 40 inputs.
- Limit input characters count for my input to 9 characters. So user can't enter more than 9 digits and never exceed max int size. I do not like this solution too.

Hope somebody has better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Range` with `MVC validation` are themselves capable of validation we don't need anything special to do.

This is what I have done and it perfectly fits the bill.

*Model*

```
public class IndexModel
{
    [Range(1, Int32.MaxValue)]
    public int? MyVariable { get; set; }
}
```

*Controller*

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IndexModel model)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

*View*

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.IndexModel
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyVariable)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MyVariable)

    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />    
}
```

Comment: I'm validating at server only. I'm looking that you have included some script to view. Is it javascript client validation?

Comment: @Vitalii, Yes and it is provide by default you can easily find it in script folder

Comment: Do you mean that if I'll include 'jquery.validate.min.js' to my page client validation will be enabled automatically? I heard about it but never use client. Only server side

Comment: @Vitalii, add script and use ValidationMessageFor as i have used. rest will be taken care of automatically

Comment: Thanks, I can try in some hours. Hope this will help =)

Comment: That was it. Client validation helped! Thanks :)